# How to insert color in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I insert a text with color. The code below will only insert normal text.

```
oDoc.Range.InsertAfter("Text Input One")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Range.Font.Color = wdColorRed
```

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/2006-08/msg00064.html

Answer (score 0):

Color is an attribute of the font of the range, so range.font.color can be read or set.